# Complex Differentiability with respect to x and y

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f=u+iv$ be C-differentiable in the whole plane C and $u=v^2$ everywhere. Show that $f=const$.

This problem is a bit challenging. I decided to express $u-v^2=0$ and take the partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$. But do not know what to do from there.

Comment: Try using the limit definitions of the derivative, in the x-direction and in the y-direction.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass, I did that as well. But how can I deduce the conclusion from there?

Comment: @user251257, bounded entire functions must be constant by the Liousville Theorem

Comment: Yeah, J.R.'s way is better.  Apologies: I was thinking of of the way one proves that a complex-differentiable, real-valued function of a complex variable has zero derivative everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is holomorphic we have

$$ u_x = (v^2)_x = 2 v v_x = v_y$$

and

$$ u_y = (v^2)_y = 2 v v_y = - v_x$$

Substituting the first into the second equation,

$$ v_y = 2 v v_x = - 2v 2 v v_y = -4v^2 v_y$$

so that

$$(1+4v^2)v_y = 0$$

This holds if either $1 + 4v^2 = 0$ or if $v_y = 0$.

If $v_y = 0$ then $v$ is a function of $x$ that is, $v = v(x)$ and therefore so is $u = v^2$. But then $u_y = 0 = - v_x$ hence $v$ must be constant hence $u=v^2$ must be constant, too.

If $1 + 4v^2 = 0$ then $v^2 = {-1\over 4}$. But $v$ is real valued hence $1 + 4v^2$ is non-zero everywhere.

Comment: actually, $v$ is real (after all it is the imaginary part of f). So $v^2$ can't be $-1/4$.

Comment: @user251257 Good point. Let me find the mistake.

Comment: There is no. It just one of two cases

Comment: @user251257 Got it. Thank you for your comments! I will edit the answer.